# Can ANOVAs or Student tests be conducted on any summary statistic at the individual level?

Tags: anova, t-test, mean, median

I am wondering if ANOVAs or Student tests can be performed on any summary statistic of performance at the individual level without any effect on type 1 and type 2 error.

For example, consider a simple experimental design with a categorical independent variable and a continuous dependent variable. For instance, human participants either drink an alcoholic or a non-alcoholic beverage, and then perform 100 trials of a detection task. The variable of interest is the response time (RT) in each trial. Researchers generally compute the mean RT for each subject, and run an ANOVA or a Student test on these individual means. Would it possible to instead compute the median RT for each subject, and run an ANOVA or a Student test on these individual medians? I think this alternative approach is valid so long as assumptions of the test are satisfied, but maybe I am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't collapse any within-subject repeated measurements of RT into a mean or median, since they're correlated.  The within-subject correlation among repeated measurements affects the overall difference between subjects (B), within subjects (W), and their interaction (BW) and therefore needs to be **preserved during the analysis**.

Collapsing into anything throws away the valuable information related to within-subject correlation. Repeated Measures ANOVA (RMANOVA) can easily handle this.  Otherwise use a longitudinal regression method that can handle all the repeated within-subject RTs, as well as the categorical grouping (treatment) variable.